# What is wrong with the function strtok()?

Tags: c, string

So, how it works?
I've the following block of code;

```
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    array[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(char));
    fgets(buffer, M-1, fp);
    array[i] = strtok(buffer, "\n");
}
```

If I execute `printf("%s", array[i]);` inside the `for` the `strtok()` works as I expected, but if I do

```
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    printf("%s", array[i]);
```

outside the previous `for`, I obtain a loop of `N` `array[0]`.

Comment: What's wrong with ignoring the `fgets` return value?

Comment: @Jens Nice catch. Should (_Must_) be part of an answer. I'll add it to mine. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `strtok` is that the token it returns you becomes invalid as soon as you make the next call of `strtok`. You could either copy it into a separate string, or use it right away, and discard, but you must use it before calling `strtok` again.

```
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    array[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(char));
    fgets(buffer, M-1, fp);
    char *tok = strtok(buffer, "\n");
    array[i] = malloc(strlen(tok)+1);
    strcpy(array[i], tok);
}
```

Of course now you need to call `free` on all elements of your `array[]` after you are done with them.

Note that `strtok` is not re-entrant, which severely limits its use. A better choice is `strtok_r`, which is a re-entrant version of the same function.

Comment: infact i copy what returned in `array[i]`, and then i call it again, still don't understand

EDIT: ok, now it's clear :)

Comment: @wing Copying should fix this particular problem with your code. There may be something else going on, but not inside the `for` loop.

Comment: i don't understand why u do an other malloc. array[i] is an array of char *, and in `array[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(char));` i already allocate memory for it's char elements

Comment: @wing Ah, I see what you are doing. You can eliminate the first `malloc`, because it allocates for the size of `M`, while the one in the answer allocates at the exact length of the token plus one for null terminator. Alternatively you could `strcpy` from `token` to `array[i]` right away, but that would not be the most efficient way of using memory.

Answer (score 2):

> **What is wrong with the function `strtok()`?**

Nothing, function works as expected. The way it is *used* here, creates the problem.

*Note: You have already received the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30832794/2173917) from  Mr. [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight), however, just to elaborate another missing point, adding this answer*.

The problems in your code are

- **Point 1.** As already mentioned, [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)  does not return a value that is *persistent* among successive calls. You've to *copy* the value of the returned token in each call, otherwise, you'll not get the expected value. For that, **either** you have to (after a sanity check of NULL token)

  - 1.1. Take a pointer, allocate memory (using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) or family) and copy the token content using [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy)
  - 1.2. use (non-standard) [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) to directly *copy* the token to `array[i]`. No need of allocating memory separately.

  FWIW, for **both** the cases, one you're done with the `array[i]`, you need to [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) it.
- **Point 2:** By allocating memory to `array[i]` using `malloc()`

  ```
  array[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(char));
  ```

  and then *assigning* another pointer to it

  ```
  array[i] =  //some pointer...
  ```

  you're *overwriting* the previously allocated pointer, thereby facing [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). Avoid this design and follow either of the above ways to get your code to work properly.

That said,

1. (just an advice) `sizeof(char)` is guranteed to produce `1` according to `C` standard. Multiplication by `sizeof(char)` is likely to be avoided.
2. Always check the return value of `fgets()` to ensure a successful *read*.